# UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque and UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent still possible despite being deprecated as of iOS 7.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uistatusbar

Is it still possible to use UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque or UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent despite being deprecated as of iOS 7.0? Does "deprecated" mean "look down upon but still allow" or "not allowed at all"?

I've tried doing a

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

in the method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

of my AppDelegate.m, but that has no effect. The Status Bar is still so garishly white, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an item is deprecated, the action, code, or such may still work or perform the dedicated action, but not in the expected way.

As such, with UI items, it is best to avoid them as further editions (8.x updates) will only break deprecated items more if not remove them fully. IF you require them, dedicate it by iOS version in `- (void)viewDidLoad` or an entire separate storyboard/xib file (not recommend as your app can become fairly large doing this).